# AngularJS getting "Missing 'use strict' statement"-errors, even tough I've included the statements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

I have a controller and two modules split in to three files. When I run the Jshint-Task in Grunt I always get the error, that the statement "use strict" is missing. So in order to fix this error, I included the statement into those three files, but I still get the error and I don't understand why. As I am still learning the basics of Angular I have no clue why this happens.

Thanks for your answers!

**The controller:**

```
"use strict";
angular.module('calculatorApp').controller('HomeController', ['calculatorApp', function(){
    var $this = this;

    $this.test = function () {
        $this.alert('test');
    };
}]);
```

**The module:**

```
"use strict";
    var  calculatorApp = angular.module('calculatorApp', ['ngRoute']);
    calculatorApp.config(function($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'home.tpl.html'
            })
        .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            })
    });
```

Comment: Pls post a sample code

Comment: 'use strict';  does not work for you? please show a plunker or more code

Comment: I've added some code samples now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to share my solution for the errors. As it seems I had a vendor folder inside of my src folder. If someone else should experience this error, check your folder structure!

Answer (score 0):

Allways wrap your modules to avoid errors in concat & miniziming tasks (avoid variable collisions & leaking to the global scope), also include use strict inside this functions.

Example:

app.js

```
var app;
(function (app) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', [
        'module1',
        'module2',
        'moduleX'
    ]);
})(app || (app = {}));
```

randomcontroller.js

```
var app;
(function (app) {
    'use strict';
    var RandomController = (function () {
        function RandomController(logger) {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.title = 'RandomView';
            this.logger.info('Activated Random View');
        }
        RandomController.$inject = ['logger'];
        return RandomController;
})();
angular.module('app').controller('RandomController', RandomController);
})(app || (app = {}));
```

Refer to the amazing John Papa's guide if have any trouble -> https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Thanks for your input about shaping my code correct, but I'm afraid it doesn't fix the errors.